# Book where a king is cursed with infertility so the queen's daughter will inherit

Tags: story-identification, books, witches

Can remember a few scenes in it. Near the beginning the queen, who is a witch, is casting a curse on her husband the king. She has a handkerchief with his seed on it that she has tied into 9 knots. The curse is so he would-be impotent with any other woman so that her daughter will rule. The only way to undo the curse is by undoing the knots. She then throws it into the fireplace for it to burn. She ends up passing away shortly after.
As the book goes on the king does end up with anther woman but can't perform, he cries about his dead wife.

His daughter also becomes a witch. There is another scene of her graduating where she has to walk through something, can't remember what, but it shows her all the pain she has caused others by her actions and inaction. And something else but can't recall.

Anyway she goes around the country to see what all is wrong with it and shows it to the king.

In the end she ends up having to fight the woman who was trying to seduce the king. The woman turns herself into a black dragon and the princess has things from 4 archangels. A wooden sword from Uriel, a white horse from Gabriel; Michael gives her his glove and she finally gets a ring from Raphael. (Who she had tried to dice with to get it.)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall the cover art?

Comment: No unfortunately I do not remember th cover art, author r anything. Think might have been late 90's when I read it